# Heroku web process crashing with code H10 and status 0: no error is provided

Tags: heroku

Hey I recently made an update to my web server hosted on heroku, i added web pages but when it starts the logs state that the web process crashed:

```
Starting process with command `node server.js`
Process exited with status 0
State changed from starting to crashed
```

server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Online on PORT ${PORT}`);
})
```

There are no errors just these 3 lines. I have been searching for a solution for the past 2 hours now and didn't find anything. I saw lots of posts on this but none solved the problem. I would appreciate any help. If I am missing something please tell me if you need more details this is my first time on this forum.

Comment: Exiting 0 usually indicates _success_. That suggests that your `server.js` runs, and then exits. Does it start a web server and bind to the port Heroku assigns? Please [edit] your question and show us the relevant part of `server.js`.

Comment: I put the server start part of the script with the port selection.

Comment: There's nothing else in that file? That's _exactly_ what it contains?

Comment: No it has some other things like database connection, discord bot client connection and routes handling `app.use('/', router)` but everything works when i run it locally on my device the problem is when i try with heroku so i don't think there is any code error

Comment: Be very careful with statements like "everything works when i run it locally on my device… so i don't think there is any code error". You should _always_ assume the problem is in your code until you prove otherwise. Since your real code does something different from what is shown here we can't help much. Please read [ask].